# Google drive pdf viewer does not work anymore on android

Tags: android, pdf, webview, google-drive-api

I have an app in android which was able to render a pdf, in a web view
The pdf is hosted online and and one of my requirements was not to download the pdf locally.

Until some days ago, I was able to fulfill every requirement by using the url

```
https://docs.google.com/gview/viewer?embed=true&url=<pdf_url>
```

Now, Google has changed this url. The new url is the following:

```
https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url=<pdf_url>
```

With the new viewer, Android do not render the pdf anymore. Instead, every time I try to load the pdf in the viewer, both the emulator and the devices show the following image:

[image: Problem while loading the pdf]

How can I solve this issue?

Thank you,

Rik

Comment: If Android is rendering the PDF, then by definition you'll have downloaded it...

Comment: That's not true... With the previous docs.google.com service, the pdf was cached by the webview but not downloaded into the device's storage...

Comment: is it possible to open it on Android 9? I don't have problems on other versions of Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Up to now, I put in place a workaround: I download the pdf in the external storage  and I launch an app to display it, by using an intent.

I keep replacing the old pdf with the new one, every time the user wants to download a new pdf. In this way, I have not to worry about the physical space in the SD and the requirement not to download the pdf locally is partially fulfilled, since at any time, there could be only one pdf stored.

I hope Google will solve the drive viewer issue as soon as possibile.

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is caused by that goole drive is https and your url is http. I testd some pdf url and find that rule